# Parent view is overlapped by child view

Tags: android, user-interface

I am developing an Android application in which I would like to display the GridView using RecyclerView.

I could able to create separate layout for an item and display it in GridView dynamically.But I face an issue in showing tick mark on top right of each item.

The tick mark is hidden by CardView [image: here]

Here is my **item_grid.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:elevation="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_hobby_bg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cycling" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_hobby_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:text="CYCLING"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_hobby_selected_icon"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/all_checked_round" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I have tried `bringToFront()` method but it is not working.

```
  viewHolder.checkMark.bringToFront();
        ((View) viewHolder.checkMark.getParent()).invalidate();
        (viewHolder.checkMark.getParent()).requestLayout();
```

Please help me find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use **elevation**.

If your card view has elevation as 10dp, then set elevation in imageView as 11dp.

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_hobby_selected_icon"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_camera"
        android:elevation="13dp"
        />
```

Comment: Great :-) Thanks a lot :-) This works like a charm with little effort :-)